# Data manipulation in JS: Finding two users with the best match

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-manipulation

I'm stuck with a problem at the moment. I have a CSV file that contains data. I've parsed it using d3.js.

It looks something like this:

```
moviesByUser = [
  {"userId":"001","values":[
    {"movieID":"222"},
    {"movieID":"333"}
  ]},
  {"userId":"045","values":[
    {"movieID":"111"}
  ]},
  {"userId":"294","values":[
    {"movieID":"222"},
    {"movieID":"333"},
    {"movieID":"789"}
  ]},
  {"userId":"246","values":[
    {"movieID":"222"},
    {"movieID":"111"},
    {"movieID":"987"}
  ]},
  {"userId":"642","values":[
    {"movieID":"222"},
    {"movieID":"111"},
    {"movieID":"333"},
    {"movieID":"789"},
  ]}
];
```

What I've been trying to do is come up with a way to find the two users with the most matches, in this case, movies. The actual data is full of 1000's of users and movies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of any particularly efficient algorithm for this.  But we can write the inefficient one fairly cleanly.

```js
// utility functions
const pairs = ([x, ...xs] = []) =>
  xs .length == 0 ? [] : xs .map (y => [x, y]) .concat (pairs (xs))

const shared = (xs = [], ys = []) => 
  xs .reduce ((t, x) => ys.includes (x) ? t + 1: t, 0)


// main function
const mostMatches = (moviesByUser) =>
  pairs (moviesByUser .map (({userId, values}) => ({
    id: userId, 
    ms: values .map (m => m .movieID)
  }))) .reduce (({ids, matches}, [x, y, t =  shared (x .ms, y .ms)]) => 
    t > matches ? {matches: t, ids: [x.id, y.id]} : {matches, ids},
    {matches: -1}
  ) 


// sample data
const moviesByUser = [{userId: "001", values: [{movieID: "222"}, {movieID: "333"}]}, {userId: "045", values: [{movieID: "111"}]}, {userId: "294", values: [{movieID: "222"}, {movieID: "333"}, {movieID: "789"}]}, {userId: "246", values: [{movieID: "222"}, {movieID: "111"}, {movieID: "987"}]}, {userId: "642", values: [{movieID: "222"}, {movieID: "111"}, {movieID: "333"}, {movieID: "789"}]}]


// demo
console .log (mostMatches (moviesByUser))
```

We first convert the elements into a slightly more useable format:

```js
  {
    "userId": "001", "values": [
      { "movieID": "222" },
      { "movieID": "333" }
    ]
  }
```

becomes

```
{id: '001', m: ['222', '333']}
```

Then we take the *`pairs`* of such elements, and fold them into a single result, using `reduce`, by counting how many *`shared`* movies are in both of their lists, updating our maximum value and user ids whenever we find a larger one.

We use two general-purpose utility functions.

- **`pairs`** takes a list of elements and returns the `n * (n - 1) / 2` pairs of elements in that list.  For instance,

  ```js
  pairs (["a", "b", "c", "d"])
  //=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["a", "d"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "d"], ["c", "d"]]
  ```
- **`shared`** takes two lists of values and counts the number of values they have in common.  For instance,

  ```js
  shared ([2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])
  //=> 4  (the four values 11, 13, 17, and 19 are in both lists.)
  ```

Our final output is something like `{matches: 3, ids: ['294', '642']}`.  With only a little more work, we could return the original users in the pair if that was needed.

The performance is going to be something like `O (n^2 * m)` where `n` is the number of users and `m` is their average number of movies.  I don't see any way to avoid the `n ^ 2`, but perhaps a clever algorithm can reduce the `m` factor.

Comment: Do you think this is possible with mongodb and mongoose?

Comment: Quite likely.  But I'm not the one to ask about that.  I would suggest opening another question if that's the direction you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

Basically create a list that stores the number matches for every pair of users. To do this more efficiantly, group the users by movie, and "pair" every new user with every user already in the list for each movie.

```js
const moviesByUser = [
  {
    "userId": "001", "values": [
      { "movieID": "222" },
      { "movieID": "333" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "userId": "045", "values": [
      { "movieID": "111" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "userId": "294", "values": [
      { "movieID": "222" },
      { "movieID": "333" },
      { "movieID": "789" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "userId": "246", "values": [
      { "movieID": "222" },
      { "movieID": "111" },
      { "movieID": "987" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "userId": "642", "values": [
      { "movieID": "222" },
      { "movieID": "111" },
      { "movieID": "333" },
      { "movieID": "789" },
    ]
  }
];

const usersByMovieID = {};
const pairs = {};
let best = 0;

// sort by number of movies DESC
moviesByUser.sort((a,b) => b.values.length - a.values.length);

for (let user of moviesByUser) {
  // since the list is sorted, no further user can win anymore; not even a tie.
  if(user.values.length < best) break;
  
  for (let { movieID } of user.values) {
    usersByMovieID[movieID] ??= [];
    for (let other of usersByMovieID[movieID]) {
      const hash = other.userId + "/" + user.userId;
      pairs[hash] = (pairs[hash] || 0) + 1;
      best = Math.max(best, pairs[hash]);
    }
    usersByMovieID[movieID].push(user);
  }
}

const result = Object.entries(pairs)
  .filter(([hash, matches]) => matches === best)
  .map(([hash, matches]) => {
    const [user1, user2] = hash.split("/");
    return { matches, user1, user2 }
  });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```